# How to read a binary file into a vector of unsigned chars

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, binaryfiles

Lately I've been asked to write a function that reads the binary file into the `std::vector<BYTE>` where `BYTE` is an `unsigned char`. Quite quickly I came with something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

std::vector<BYTE> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:
    std::streampos fileSize;
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // get its size:
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // read the data:
    std::vector<BYTE> fileData(fileSize);
    file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
    return fileData;
}
```

which seems to be unnecessarily complicated and the explicit cast to `char*` that I was forced to use while calling `file.read` doesn't make me feel any better about it.

---

Another option is to use [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/):

```
std::vector<BYTE> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // read the data:
    return std::vector<BYTE>((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}
```

which is pretty simple and short, but still I have to use the `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` even when I'm reading into `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

---

The last option that seems to be perfectly straightforward is to use [`std::basic_ifstream<BYTE>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), which kinda expresses it explicitly that *"I want an input file stream and I want to use it to read `BYTE`s"*:

```
std::vector<BYTE> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:
    std::basic_ifstream<BYTE> file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // read the data:
    return std::vector<BYTE>((std::istreambuf_iterator<BYTE>(file)),
                              std::istreambuf_iterator<BYTE>());
}
```

but I'm not sure whether [`basic_ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) is an appropriate choice in this case.

*What is the best way of reading a binary file into the `vector`?* I'd also like to know what's happening *"behind the scene"* and what are the possible problems I might encounter (apart from stream not being opened properly which might be avoided by simple [`is_open`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/) check).

Is there any good reason why one would prefer to use [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/) here?
(the only advantage that I can see is simplicity)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: What I meant with it was that 3rd option doesn't seem to be any better than 2nd option.

Comment: someone measured it (in 2011) , for loading into string at least. http://insanecoding.blogspot.hk/2011/11/how-to-read-in-file-in-c.html

Comment: A safer way to find the size: use the special [`ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)  count: `file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());`, and return the `std::streamsize` 'extracted' using `auto size =`[`file.gcount();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When testing for performance, I would include a test case for:

```
std::vector<BYTE> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // Stop eating new lines in binary mode!!!
    file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    // get its size:
    std::streampos fileSize;

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // reserve capacity
    std::vector<BYTE> vec;
    vec.reserve(fileSize);

    // read the data:
    vec.insert(vec.begin(),
               std::istream_iterator<BYTE>(file),
               std::istream_iterator<BYTE>());

    return vec;
}
```

My thinking is that the constructor of Method 1 touches the elements in the `vector`, and then the `read` touches each element again.

Method 2 and Method 3 look most promising, but could suffer one or more `resize`'s. Hence the reason to `reserve` before reading or inserting.

I would also test with `std::copy`:

```
...
std::vector<byte> vec;
vec.reserve(fileSize);

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<BYTE>(file),
          std::istream_iterator<BYTE>(),
          std::back_inserter(vec));
```

In the end, I think the best solution will avoid `operator >>` from `istream_iterator` (and all the overhead and goodness from `operator >>` trying to interpret binary data). But I don't know what to use that allows you to directly copy the data into the vector.

Finally, my testing with binary data is showing `ios::binary` is not being honored. Hence the reason for `noskipws` from `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Is there a way to read a specific size into the array instead of the whole file as described here?

Comment: I thought you only need `file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);` if using the operator>>

Comment: I needed `file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);` even when using `std::copy` to copy to a `vector`, otherwise I would lost data. This was with Boost 1.53.0.

Comment: @jiggunjer `std::istream_iterator` uses `>>` operator internally to extract data from the stream.

Comment: Tried more than 8 snippet, none of them worked but this , Thanks a lot! +1

Comment: It seems we don't need add file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws) under gcc 8.2.0

Comment: Use of vector::insert() and iterators is awfully slow. Probably because of calling a lot of virtual functions that read each byte. I cannot even wait until it finishes reading a huge file (3 GB in  my case), and this is in Release mode.

By changing the last part to this I got a multitude of speedup.

`std::vector<uint8_t> vec;`
`vec.resize(fileSize);`
`file.read(reinterpret_cast<std::ifstream::char_type*>(&vec.front()), fileSize);`

Comment: @jww Can I use the function `readFile` under a Apache 2.0 License?

Answer (score 31):

```
std::ifstream stream("mona-lisa.raw", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::vector<uint8_t> contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

for(auto i: contents) {
    int value = i;
    std::cout << "data: " << value << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "file size: " << contents.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't give any errors (no exception or anything). You just get empty `contents`. You can check for file errors with `if (!stream)` but I don't know if there is any way to check for read errors.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are loading the entire file into memory the most optimal version is to map the file into memory. This is because the kernel loads the file into kernel page cache anyway and by mapping the file you just expose those pages in the cache into your process. Also known as zero-copy.

When you use `std::vector<>` it copies the data from the kernel page cache into `std::vector<>` which is unnecessary when you just want to read the file.

Also, when passing two input iterators to `std::vector<>` it grows its buffer while reading because it does not know the file size. When resizing `std::vector<>` to the file size first it needlessly zeroes out its contents because it is going to be overwritten with file data anyway. Both of the methods are sub-optimal in terms of space and time.

Comment: Yes, if the content doesn't need to be in a vector, that is definitely the best method.

Comment: rather than `resize`, `reserve` doesnt initialize.

Comment: meaning you can pass the iterators to a reserved vector to avoid redundant resizing. Referring to your last paragraph.

Comment: @jiggunjer Well, that would not work because you cannot access the reserved capacity without resizing the vector first.

Comment: I don't understand. If you use `reserve(x)` no reallocation will happen if you add less than x elements to the vector.

Comment: @jiggunjer Ah, I understand now that what you are saying is already in the accepted answer...

Comment: For someone reading without reference to the standard, this is unclear. It doesn't explain _how_ to map to memory - I _assume_ `streambuf` and `basic` do this?. Also, the terminology assumes Linux/UNIX is the OS used, which feels like it might not be applicable for all platforms - do the same concepts and best practices exist in all OSes targetable by C++?

Comment: @underscore_d C++ standard library does not provide portable facilities for mapping files into memory. Boost does, see Boost Interprecess library, [Memory Mapped Files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file) for more details.

Comment: @underscore_d I assume Linux OS because it is free to use, learn and modify and plenty of free documentation is available.

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought that the first method, using the size and using `stream::read()` would be the most efficient. The "cost" of casting to `char *` is most likely zero - casts of this kind simply tell the compiler that "Hey, I know you think this is a different type, but I really want this type here...", and does not add any extra instrucitons - if you wish to confirm this, try reading the file into a char array, and compare the actual assembler code. Aside from a little bit of extra work to figure out the address of the buffer inside the vector, there shouldn't be any difference.

As always, the only way to tell for sure IN YOUR CASE what is the most efficient is to measure it. "Asking on the internet" is not proof.

Answer (score 0):

The class below extends vector with a binary file load and save. I returned to this question multiple times already, so this is the code for my next return - and for all others who will be looking for the binary file save method next. :)

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// The class offers entire file content read/write in single operation
class BinaryFileVector : public std::vector<uint8_t>
{
    public:

        using std::vector<uint8_t>::vector;

        bool loadFromFile(const char *fileName) noexcept
        {
            // Try to open a file specified by its name
            std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
            if (!file.is_open() || file.bad())
                return false;

            // Clear whitespace removal flag
            file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

            // Determine size of the file
            file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
            size_t fileSize = file.tellg();
            file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

            // Discard previous vector content
            resize(0);
            reserve(0);
            shrink_to_fit();

            // Order to prealocate memory to avoid unnecessary reallocations due to vector growth
            reserve(fileSize);

            // Read entire file content into prealocated vector memory
            insert(begin(),
                std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(file),
                std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>());

            // Make sure entire content is loaded
            return size() == fileSize;
        }

        bool saveToFile(const char *fileName) const noexcept
        {
            // Write entire vector content into a file specified by its name
            std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
            try {
                file.write((const char *) data(), size());
            }
            catch (...) {
                return false;
            }

            // Determine number of bytes successfully stored in file
            size_t fileSize = file.tellp();
            return size() == fileSize;
        }
};
```

Usage example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    BinaryFileVector binaryFileVector;

    if (!binaryFileVector.loadFromFile("data.bin")) {
        std::cout << "Failed to read a file." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!binaryFileVector.saveToFile("copy.bin")) {
        std::cout << "Failed to write a file." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```