# How to read the binary file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io, binaryfiles

I want to write a program that opens the binary file and encrypts it using DES.

But how can I read the binary file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Note that you should provide more information. Also it doesn't show any effort of yours. What have you tried? Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> *"how can I read the binary file?"*

If you want to read the binary file and then process its data (encrypt it, compress, etc.), then it seems reasonable to load it into the memory in a form that will be easy to work with. I recommend you to use `std::vector<BYTE>` where `BYTE` is an `unsigned char`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

std::vector<BYTE> readFile(const char* filename)
{
    // open the file:
    std::streampos fileSize;
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // get its size:
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // read the data:
    std::vector<BYTE> fileData(fileSize);
    file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
    return fileData;
}
```

with this function you can easily load your file into the vector like this:

```
std::vector<BYTE> fileData = readFile("myfile.bin");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It'd be cool if the OP inherited `std::fstream` and created a `fencryptstream' that did the encoding decoding transparently inside the class.

Comment: LihO "can this work with large file that size up to 250MB please help me"

Comment: @MohmmadAL-helawe: If you are experiencing some problems with large files, then post it as a new question :) Just make sure that you describe your problem properly, so that people can help you :)

Comment: for future ref) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15138353/10027592) question by LihO, for more discussion.