# Loading Wav File into Memory for PlaySound

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wav

I am trying to load a .wav file into memory so that I can play it using the PlaySound function.

Currently, I am able to play the sound with this line of code.

```
PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\DEV\\beep-07a.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

The problem is I am also displaying graphics when the sound is made, and when the sound plays, the graphics freeze while it is being played. I am assuming that this is due to the fact that the .wav file is being read from the disk each time it is played, and not from memory.

I did some searching and see that I can either load the file directly into my memory buffer or can use a resource file to do this, but I was unable to find any good resources on how to do this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you execute `PlaySound` on main thread? If you did that, try to do music playback on another thread use `CreateThread`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/playing-wave-resources

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resolve the issue of PlaySound blocking your thread, you can adjust your call like so

```c
PlaySound(..., SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

From the documentation, including this will change the behaviour such that

> The sound is played asynchronously and PlaySound returns immediately after beginning the sound. To terminate an asynchronously played waveform sound, call PlaySound with pszSound set to NULL.

If performance is a concern, you can bundle the sound into a [resource file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files) which you can link with your program, and instead load your resource by an ID rather than file path.

Comment: I made that change and now the graphics don't freeze but there is a long delay (around 2 seconds) from when I press the key to when the sound plays.

Comment: Testing with a local file on my machine has no noticeable delay even when reading from the filesystem. Are you reading from a network drive or hard drive that has a noticeable amount of latency? Or, does your audio file have a period of silence at the start?

Comment: "*you can bundle the sound into a resource file*" - or into a memory buffer (played with `SND_MEMORY`) if you want the `.wav` to stay as a separate file instead of embedding it in the `.exe` file (ie, if you want users to be able to use custom `.wav` files).

Comment: @mitch_ So I went and tried it again and noticed something this time.  I have different sections of my graphics rendering, one section where I am just rendering a static image and another where I am rendering three circles that are controlled by an external device. When I use your version of the PlaySound call on and make the sound on the static image screen, it works perfectly, but when I make the sound while rendering the three circles, there is a delay between the keypress and the production of the sound.

Answer (score 1):

There are existing questions for reading a file into a memory buffer, such as:

[C++ read the whole file in buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816126)
[Reading file into buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959940)
[How to read a binary file into a vector of unsigned chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138353)
just to name a few...

Once you have the WAV file data in memory, simply pass a pointer to the WAV data in memory to `PlaySound()`, specifying the `SND_MEMORY` flag, eg:

```
PlaySound((LPCTSTR)data_pointer, NULL, SND_MEMORY);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do this (using the first link) and play the sound from the memory buffer but unfortunately that did not help. I am having the same issue of the graphics freezing when I play the sound. I think I need to figure out how to play the sound in it's own thread, I was able to create a thread for sound but am still working on playing the sound within it.

Comment: "*I am having the same issue of the graphics freezing when I play the sound*" - I never said this would solve that. That issue happens when you play the sound *synchronously* on the same thread that handles the graphics. So either 1) play the sound *asynchronously*, or 2) move the playback to a different thread.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Playing the sound asynchronously still ends up with the delay issue I mentioned so I'm going to try and get it to work in a different thread, appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but just using `sndPlaySound` instead of `PlaySound` fixed the latency and all of the freezing issues I was having with my graphics without needing to create a new thread or even having to load the file into my memory buffer. This was the line of code I ended up using.

```
 sndPlaySound(TEXT("C:\\DEV\\beep-07a.wav"), SND_ASYNC | SND_NOSTOP);
```

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. Just a reminder :)